# Set value of people picker client side

Tags: jquery, people-picker

I'm using SharePoint 2013 people picker client side, how can I set a default user using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you have a look at SPServices.
They have a method that fits your need

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker

Comment: Is that library already included in SP13?

Comment: It's a third party, open-source library. On the link I provided you'll find all the details

Comment: Do you know which is the DisplayName (name of the column which is shown on forms)  for the default people picker? (display users)

Comment: Fire open your browser developer toolbar and hover over the picker with the inspector tool

Comment: Is possible to set the displayName?

Comment: not sure what you mean with DisplayName, anyhow, what is shown in forms is the column title. If you change it, it will change accordingly

Comment: I just see "Enter a name or email address..."

Comment: do you mean the value of the PeoplePicker field? You can set it to a value by using SPServices

Comment: Best solution here:
http://blog.ianchivers.com/2013/05/client-side-people-picker-control-for.html